# Type casting in C++ by detecting the current 'this' object type

Tags: c++, rtti

My question is related to RTTI in C++ where I'm trying to check if an object belongs to the type hierarchy of another object. The BelongsTo() method checks this. 
I tried using typeid, but it throws an error and I'm not sure about any other way how I can find the target type to convert to at runtime.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class X
{
    public:
        //  Checks if the input type belongs to the type heirarchy of input object type
        bool BelongsTo(X* p_a)
        {
            //  I'm trying to check if the current (this) type belongs to the same type 
            //  hierarchy as the input type
            return dynamic_cast<typeid(*p_a)*>(this) != NULL;   //  error C2059: syntax error 'typeid'
        }
};

class A : public X
{
};

class B : public A
{
};

class C : public A
{
};

int main()
{
    X* a = new A();
    X* b = new B();
    X* c = new C();
    bool test1 = b->BelongsTo(a);   // should return true
    bool test2 = b->BelongsTo(c);   // should return false
    bool test3 = c->BelongsTo(a);   // should return true
}
```

Making the method virtual and letting derived classes do it seems like a bad idea as I have a lot of classes in the same type hierarchy.
Or does anybody know of any other/better way to the do the same thing? Please suggest.

**Update**: b.BelongsTo(a) should detect if the input object type (a) is an ancestor of the current object (b) in the type hierarchy.

Comment: While I'm not sure this can be done properly, I don't either how this *could be* useful. Just out of curiosity, why do you want to achieve this ?

Comment: Please see the comments on Neil's answer for an example.

Comment: For eg. C derives from B derives from A, X derives from A. In some cases I may need to verify that the object type I receive pointed to by the base class pointer (A*) should be of type B and not of type X, failing which I'll throw an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't make sense - the very fact that you can call the function means that the parameter belongs to the X hierarchy, as that is the type of the parameter. Dynamic casts are intended to find out the actual type within a known hierarchy.

The syntax error in your code:

```
return dynamic_cast<typeid(*p_a)*>(this) != NULL;
```

is because a typeid is not a type - you simply cannot use it as a type with dynamic_cast like that.

If as Naveen suggests you want to find out if an instance belongs to a sub-hierarchy, use:

```
if ( dynamic_cast <A*>( some_x_ptr ) ) {

    // yes, belongs to A sub-hierarchy
}
```

**Edit:** You have:

```
A <- P <- X
A <- Q <- Y
```

**Then:**

```
A * a = new X;

dynamic_cast <P *>( a );   // not null
dynamic_cast <Q *>( a );   // null
```

Comment: Notice that `class B` and `class C` are derived from `class A`. I think the intention of OP is to find whether the passed objects belongs to this sub-hierarchy or not.

Comment: I apologize for not making myself really clear here. For eg. X derives from P, Y derives from Q, where P and Q derive from A. So, X belongs to P and A, Y belongs to Q and A but X does not belong to Q. I need this behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a name for this kind of detection but it looks like checking for ancestors.

Comment: Awesome, now how do you think this fits into the code I have written. If you try that maybe you'll get a better picture of what I'm trying to do. What changes in BelongsTo() would be needed?

Comment: @Elroy You can't write it as a normal function because the thing in the angle brackets must be known at compile time. You could write it as a template (I think).

Comment: Okay. The best solution is then to make it virtual and provide implementation in all subclasses, right?

Comment: @Elroy No, the best solution is simply to use dynamic_cast, which does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

In order for RTTI to work `class X` needs at least one virtual member function (virtual destructor counts as well). Without virtual member functions the class will not have a vtable generated by the compiler and so when you invoke `typeid` the latter will not work as you expect.

Comment: I added a virtual destructor in each class. But it still shows that syntax error. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, see Neil Butterworth's answer.